# _update-rc.d vncserver-x11-serviced defaults_ COMMAND = There is a loop between service rc.local and mountkernfs if started... ERROR

Tags: debian, boot, vnc

I have the latest version of Debian and have installed [RealVNC](http://www.realvnc.com/) on it. After installation I tried to `autorun RealVNC` when the system boots.

So I found this: [vncserver-x11-serviced - VNC® X11 Service-mode Daemon](http://www.realvnc.com/products/vnc/documentation/5.0/misc/reference/vncserver-x11-serviced).

After running this command:

```
$ update-rc.d vncserver-x11-serviced defaults
```

I've got the error below:

> update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing insserv: warning:
>   script 'S99selinux' missing LSB tags and overrides insserv: warning:
>   script 'S97DbSecuritySpt' missing LSB tags and overrides insserv:
>   warning: script 'S77.SSH2' missing LSB tags and overrides insserv:
>   warning: script 'S77.SSHH2' missing LSB tags and overrides insserv:
>   warning: script 'DbSecuritySpt' missing LSB tags and overrides
>   insserv: warning: script 'selinux' missing LSB tags and overrides
>   insserv: There is a loop at service selinux if started insserv: There
>   is a loop between service selinux and mountnfs if started insserv: 
>   loop involving service mountnfs at depth 7 insserv:  loop involving
>   service networking at depth 6 insserv:  loop involving service
>   console-screen at depth 9 insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on rc.local
>   and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
>   insserv: Starting .SSHH2 depends on rc.local and therefore on system
>   facility`$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends
>   on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be
>   true! insserv: Starting .SSHH2 depends on rc.local and therefore on
>   system facility`$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting .SSH2
>   depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can
>   not be true! insserv: Starting .SSHH2 depends on rc.local and
>   therefore on system facility`$all' which can not be true! insserv:
>   Starting .SSH2 depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility
>   `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting .SSHH2 depends on
>   rc.local and therefore on system facility`$all' which can not be
>   true! insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on rc.local and therefore on
>   system facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting .SSHH2
>   depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility`$all' which can
>   not be true! insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on rc.local and therefore
>   on system facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting
>   .SSHH2 depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility`$all'
>   which can not be true! insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on rc.local and
>   therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv:
>   Starting .SSHH2 depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility`
>   $all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on
>   rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be
>   true! insserv: Starting .SSHH2 depends on rc.local and therefore on
>   system facility`$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting .SSH2
>   depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can
>   not be true! insserv: Starting .SSHH2 depends on rc.local and
>   therefore on system facility`$all' which can not be true! insserv:
>   Starting .SSH2 depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility
>   `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting .SSHH2 depends on
>   rc.local and therefore on system facility`$all' which can not be
>   true! insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on rc.local and therefore on
>   system facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting .SSHH2
>   depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility`$all' which can
>   not be true! insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on rc.local and therefore
>   on system facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting
>   .SSHH2 depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility`$all'
>   which can not be true! insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on rc.local and
>   therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv:
>   Starting .SSHH2 depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility`
>   $all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on
>   rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be
>   true! insserv: Starting .SSHH2 depends on rc.local and therefore on
>   system facility`$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting .SSH2
>   depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can
>   not be true! insserv: Starting .SSHH2 depends on rc.local and
>   therefore on system facility`$all' which can not be true! insserv:
>   Starting .SSH2 depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility
>   `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting .SSHH2 depends on
>   rc.local and therefore on system facility`$all' which can not be
>   true! insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on rc.local and therefore on
>   system facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting .SSHH2
>   depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility`$all' which can
>   not be true! insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on rc.local and therefore
>   on system facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting
>   .SSHH2 depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility`$all'
>   which can not be true! insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on rc.local and
>   therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv:
>   Starting .SSHH2 depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility`
>   $all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on
>   rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be
>   true! insserv: Starting .SSHH2 depends on rc.local and therefore on
>   system facility`$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting .SSH2
>   depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can
>   not be true! insserv: Starting .SSHH2 depends on rc.local and
>   therefore on system facility`$all' which can not be true! insserv:
>   Starting .SSH2 depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility
>   `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting .SSHH2 depends on
>   rc.local and therefore on system facility`$all' which can not be
>   true! insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on rc.local and therefore on
>   system facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting .SSHH2
>   depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility`$all' which can
>   not be true! insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on rc.local and therefore
>   on system facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting
>   .SSHH2 depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility`$all'
>   which can not be true! insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on rc.local and
>   therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv:
>   Starting .SSHH2 depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility`
>   $all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on
>   rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be
>   true! insserv: Starting .SSHH2 depends on rc.local and therefore on
>   system facility`$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting .SSH2
>   depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can
>   not be true! insserv: Starting .SSHH2 depends on rc.local and
>   therefore on system facility`$all' which can not be true! insserv:
>   Starting .SSH2 depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility
>   `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting .SSHH2 depends on
>   rc.local and therefore on system facility`$all' which can not be
>   true! insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on rc.local and therefore on
>   system facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting .SSHH2
>   depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility`$all' which can
>   not be true! insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on rc.local and therefore
>   on system facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting
>   .SSHH2 depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility`$all'
>   which can not be true! insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on rc.local and
>   therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv:
>   Starting .SSHH2 depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility`
>   $all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on
>   rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be
>   true! insserv: Starting .SSHH2 depends on rc.local and therefore on
>   system facility`$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting .SSH2
>   depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can
>   not be true! insserv: Starting .SSHH2 depends on rc.local and
>   therefore on system facility`$all' which can not be true! insserv:
>   Starting .SSH2 depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility
>   `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting .SSHH2 depends on
>   rc.local and therefore on system facility`$all' which can not be
>   true! insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on rc.local and therefore on
>   system facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting .SSHH2
>   depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility`$all' which can
>   not be true! insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on rc.local and therefore
>   on system facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting
>   .SSHH2 depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility`$all'
>   which can not be true! insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on rc.local and
>   therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv:
>   Starting .SSHH2 depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility`
>   $all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on
>   rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be
>   true! insserv: Starting .SSHH2 depends on rc.local and therefore on
>   system facility`$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting .SSH2
>   depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can
>   not be true! insserv: Starting .SSHH2 depends on rc.local and
>   therefore on system facility`$all' which can not be true! insserv:
>   Starting .SSH2 depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility
>   `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting .SSHH2 depends on
>   rc.local and therefore on system facility`$all' which can not be
>   true! insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on rc.local and therefore on
>   system facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting .SSHH2
>   depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility`$all' which can
>   not be true! insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on rc.local and therefore
>   on system facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting
>   .SSHH2 depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility`$all'
>   which can not be true! insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on rc.local and
>   therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv:
>   Starting .SSHH2 depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility`
>   $all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on
>   rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be
>   true! insserv: Starting .SSHH2 depends on rc.local and therefore on
>   system facility`$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting .SSH2
>   depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can
>   not be true! insserv: Starting .SSHH2 depends on rc.local and
>   therefore on system facility`$all' which can not be true! insserv:
>   Starting .SSH2 depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility
>   `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting .SSHH2 depends on
>   rc.local and therefore on system facility`$all' which can not be
>   true! insserv: Starting .SSH2 depends on rc.local and therefore on
>   system facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting .SSHH2
>   depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility`$all' which can
>   not be true! insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached insserv:  loop
>   involving service thin at depth 14 insserv: There is a loop at service
>   rc.local if started insserv: Starting selinux depends on single and
>   therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv:
>   Starting DbSecuritySpt depends on single and therefore on system
>   facility`$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting selinux
>   depends on single and therefore on system facility `$all' which can
>   not be true! insserv: Starting DbSecuritySpt depends on single and
>   therefore on system facility`$all' which can not be true! insserv:
>   Starting selinux depends on single and therefore on system facility
>   `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting DbSecuritySpt depends
>   on single and therefore on system facility`$all' which can not be
>   true! insserv: Starting selinux depends on single and therefore on
>   system facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting
>   DbSecuritySpt depends on single and therefore on system facility`
>   $all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting selinux depends on
>   single and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
>   insserv: Starting DbSecuritySpt depends on single and therefore on
>   system facility`$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting
>   selinux depends on single and therefore on system facility `$all'
>   which can not be true! insserv: Starting DbSecuritySpt depends on
>   single and therefore on system facility`$all' which can not be true!
>   insserv: Starting selinux depends on single and therefore on system
>   facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting DbSecuritySpt
>   depends on single and therefore on system facility`$all' which can
>   not be true! insserv: Starting selinux depends on single and therefore
>   on system facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting
>   DbSecuritySpt depends on single and therefore on system facility`
>   $all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting selinux depends on
>   single and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
>   insserv: Starting DbSecuritySpt depends on single and therefore on
>   system facility`$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting
>   selinux depends on single and therefore on system facility `$all'
>   which can not be true! insserv: Starting DbSecuritySpt depends on
>   single and therefore on system facility`$all' which can not be true!
>   insserv: Starting selinux depends on single and therefore on system
>   facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting DbSecuritySpt
>   depends on single and therefore on system facility`$all' which can
>   not be true! insserv: Starting selinux depends on single and therefore
>   on system facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting
>   DbSecuritySpt depends on single and therefore on system facility`
>   $all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting selinux depends on
>   single and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
>   insserv: Starting DbSecuritySpt depends on single and therefore on
>   system facility`$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting
>   selinux depends on single and therefore on system facility `$all'
>   which can not be true! insserv: Starting DbSecuritySpt depends on
>   single and therefore on system facility`$all' which can not be true!
>   insserv: Starting selinux depends on single and therefore on system
>   facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting DbSecuritySpt
>   depends on single and therefore on system facility`$all' which can
>   not be true! insserv: Starting selinux depends on single and therefore
>   on system facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting
>   DbSecuritySpt depends on single and therefore on system facility`
>   $all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting selinux depends on
>   single and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
>   insserv: Starting DbSecuritySpt depends on single and therefore on
>   system facility`$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting
>   selinux depends on single and therefore on system facility `$all'
>   which can not be true! insserv: Starting DbSecuritySpt depends on
>   single and therefore on system facility`$all' which can not be true!
>   insserv: Starting selinux depends on single and therefore on system
>   facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting DbSecuritySpt
>   depends on single and therefore on system facility`$all' which can
>   not be true! insserv: Starting selinux depends on single and therefore
>   on system facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting
>   DbSecuritySpt depends on single and therefore on system facility`
>   $all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting selinux depends on
>   single and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
>   insserv: Starting DbSecuritySpt depends on single and therefore on
>   system facility`$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting
>   selinux depends on single and therefore on system facility `$all'
>   which can not be true! insserv: Starting DbSecuritySpt depends on
>   single and therefore on system facility`$all' which can not be true!
>   insserv: Starting selinux depends on single and therefore on system
>   facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting DbSecuritySpt
>   depends on single and therefore on system facility`$all' which can
>   not be true! insserv: Starting selinux depends on single and therefore
>   on system facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting
>   DbSecuritySpt depends on single and therefore on system facility`
>   $all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting selinux depends on
>   single and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
>   insserv: Starting DbSecuritySpt depends on single and therefore on
>   system facility`$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting
>   selinux depends on single and therefore on system facility `$all'
>   which can not be true! insserv: Starting DbSecuritySpt depends on
>   single and therefore on system facility`$all' which can not be true!
>   insserv: Starting selinux depends on single and therefore on system
>   facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting DbSecuritySpt
>   depends on single and therefore on system facility`$all' which can
>   not be true! insserv: Starting selinux depends on single and therefore
>   on system facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting
>   DbSecuritySpt depends on single and therefore on system facility`
>   $all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting selinux depends on
>   single and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
>   insserv: Starting DbSecuritySpt depends on single and therefore on
>   system facility`$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting
>   selinux depends on single and therefore on system facility `$all'
>   which can not be true! insserv: Starting DbSecuritySpt depends on
>   single and therefore on system facility`$all' which can not be true!
>   insserv: Starting selinux depends on single and therefore on system
>   facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting DbSecuritySpt
>   depends on single and therefore on system facility`$all' which can
>   not be true! insserv: Starting selinux depends on single and therefore
>   on system facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting
>   DbSecuritySpt depends on single and therefore on system facility`
>   $all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting selinux depends on
>   single and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
>   insserv: Starting DbSecuritySpt depends on single and therefore on
>   system facility`$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting
>   selinux depends on single and therefore on system facility `$all'
>   which can not be true! insserv: Starting DbSecuritySpt depends on
>   single and therefore on system facility`$all' which can not be true!
>   insserv: Starting selinux depends on single and therefore on system
>   facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting DbSecuritySpt
>   depends on single and therefore on system facility`$all' which can
>   not be true! insserv: Starting selinux depends on single and therefore
>   on system facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting
>   DbSecuritySpt depends on single and therefore on system facility`
>   $all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting selinux depends on
>   single and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
>   insserv: Starting DbSecuritySpt depends on single and therefore on
>   system facility`$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting
>   selinux depends on single and therefore on system facility `$all'
>   which can not be true! insserv: Starting DbSecuritySpt depends on
>   single and therefore on system facility`$all' which can not be true!
>   insserv: Starting selinux depends on single and therefore on system
>   facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting DbSecuritySpt
>   depends on single and therefore on system facility`$all' which can
>   not be true! insserv: Starting selinux depends on single and therefore
>   on system facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting
>   DbSecuritySpt depends on single and therefore on system facility`
>   $all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting selinux depends on
>   single and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
>   insserv: Starting DbSecuritySpt depends on single and therefore on
>   system facility`$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting
>   selinux depends on single and therefore on system facility `$all'
>   which can not be true! insserv: Starting DbSecuritySpt depends on
>   single and therefore on system facility`$all' which can not be true!
>   insserv: Starting selinux depends on single and therefore on system
>   facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting DbSecuritySpt
>   depends on single and therefore on system facility`$all' which can
>   not be true! insserv: Starting selinux depends on single and therefore
>   on system facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting
>   DbSecuritySpt depends on single and therefore on system facility`
>   $all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting selinux depends on
>   single and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
>   insserv: Starting DbSecuritySpt depends on single and therefore on
>   system facility`$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting
>   selinux depends on single and therefore on system facility `$all'
>   which can not be true! insserv: Starting DbSecuritySpt depends on
>   single and therefore on system facility`$all' which can not be true!
>   insserv: Starting selinux depends on single and therefore on system
>   facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting DbSecuritySpt
>   depends on single and therefore on system facility`$all' which can
>   not be true! insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached insserv:  loop
>   involving service selinux at depth 3 insserv: Max recursions depth 99
>   reached insserv: There is a loop at service single if started insserv:
>   There is a loop between service rc.local and mountkernfs if started
>   insserv:  loop involving service mountkernfs at depth 1 insserv:
>   exiting now without changing boot order! update-rc.d: error: insserv
>   rejected the script header

What does that error mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: thanks for the upvote, i think it's a bug. any idea?

Comment: Can you repost the output from that command and format it as a code sample? That wall of text isn't helping anyone to answer your Q.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you got trojan Linux.BackDoor.Gates.5
if you see /etc/init.d/.SSH /etc/sfewfesfs  - check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23292718/am-i-hacked-unknow-processes-dsfref-gfhddsfew-dsfref-etc-are-starting-automa

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Failed sysv script "DbSecuritySpt" with missing LSB variables and SSH2 are very typical behaviour for this trojan. I have some experience with this on my servers. rkhunter and chkrootkit can't see penetration but fresh clamav will indicate the problem like "Trojan.Agent", just run clamscan -r on /etc /usr. I can't find any details except http://news.drweb.com/show/?i=5801&lng=en